# javascript not setting the value of the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swift

I made an iOS app in swift which loads a webview (link to a form). Then the user can select an input field and hit the scan button to scan a barcode. I collect the document.activeElement and run another function which will set the input field's value to the barcode scanned. Here is my javascript code :-

```
//before scanning the barcode
myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(
    from: "var abc = document.activeElement;"
) 

//after the barcode is scanned
myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(
    from: "function fillText(myValue){
        if( document.selection ){
            abc.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text=myValue;
        } else if( abc.selectionStart||abc.selectionStart == '0' ){
            var startPos = abc.selectionStart; 
            var endPos = abc.selectionEnd;
            abc.value = abc.value.substring(0,startPos)+ myValue + abc.value.substring(endPos, abc.value.length); 
            abc.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            abc.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        }else{
            abc.value += myValue;
        }   
    }"
)
```

But the input field in not filled correctly. When the user submits the form it comes empty unless something is typed. I have attached some screenshots too. We can see the text making a layer over the placeholder. Maybe there is something wrong with my JavaScript.[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyUla.png)

[Here is the screenshot when I tried to edit the source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWAN.jpg)

Comment: So In the screenshot I see the text in gray "Your Answer" underneath the #'s. that is what you are trying to get rid of?

Comment: Can you inspect elements on the place where the #'s and placeholder text is happening and Post the html or take a screenshot of the html?

Comment: the form is made by google. I just inject the javaScript. It's not just getting rid of the placeholder. When I submit those answers don't come to me. It just comes as a blank field.

Comment: Mmm I was hoping this was an html issue, but maybe not so simple as that. have to work on something else, ill check back later if no one else answers.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. So for the code block 'after the barcode is scanned' what if else block does it go into in the case where they do the barcode scan? the last one?  2. if you set the element as the activeElement `.focus()` before setting the value, does that help? `abc.focus(); abc.value += myValue`

Comment: Ans 1:- Yes it does go in the last one. Ans 2:- No abc.focus() ; abc.value += myValue doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo Shez,

So normally i debug websites not phone apps, I don't know how/ if there is a way to inspect the raw html or whatnot of the phone app.

I have read of similar issues with websites, that use **multiple overlapping input fields** then make it look like just 1 input field. That is my best guess as to what is the issue **you** are having. Somehow you are populating the value of an input field but there is a 2nd input field that is not getting your value, and not passing along the value when form submitted.

Example:
Go to Facebook and in the search box if you: **right click > inspect elements**:
[image]

You will see there are multiple **< input >** elements, not just 1:

[image]

If we then populate the .value of the secondary input field with this code on the console:
`document.getElementsByClassName('_5eay')[0].value = "VVVV"`

it overlaps with the main input placeholder text

[image]

However if we populate the .value of the main input feld with this code on the console:
`document.getElementsByClassName('_1frb')[0].value = "shez"`

The Placeholder text goes away:

[image]

1 way to maybe test this is in your code try setting the text color to pink of the input field you are changing:

`}else{
        abc.style='color:pink'
        abc.value += myValue;
 }`

Then if you add a few more characters manually typing into the field, after scanning the barcode, does the text stay pink?

**Edit:**
Here is the 2 seperate elements 1 is the input field and one is a div that has the 'Your Answer' text:
[image]

Comment: here is a link to my form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc0G2fYgynCcZMWbvYGJV3xA4dLdrZRpPpKbt_BwMP2L8muOw/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: The text never changed to pink but when I manually type 1 character after thee scanned string the placeholder goes away.

Comment: Thank you @NickTimmer. I have edit the question and add the image at the end please take a look at that as I can only see one input field there.

Comment: to make the placeholder text go away try: `abc.nextSibling.innerHTML = "";  abc.value += myValue;`

Comment: I'm not understanding WHY your not getting the value when the submit happens. I can see the value if I do: `fd = new FormData( document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0] );
fd.get("entry.1070944465")`

Comment: can you make sure `abc` is actually the <input> div `console.log("abc="+abc.nodeName);` since you don't see the text turning pink i'm skeptical that it is.

Comment: I am sorry google form was just to show the problem. the real form is here:- https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=AP9Cy-HC6EGR6cpv3BBIhRsqnbX-KkBCteAA42gnHbxUOEpUWUQ1RDBKOU9IQjdCNkIwRUhQVVI4TC4u  . The placeholder goes away but the response is blank. Here is the link to the developer's access so you can see the response:- https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx?fragment=FormId%3DAP9Cy-HC6EGR6cpv3BBIhRsqnbX-KkBCteAA42gnHbxUOEpUWUQ1RDBKOU9IQjdCNkIwRUhQVVI4TC4u%26Token%3Dbec12d7ffd324298b0b482a97c35002c .

Comment: **Update:-** Just got to know that it enters the second if condition. Not the last one

Comment: I tried adding the `console.log("abc="+abc.nodeName);` it gave me this:- **abc= INPUT**

Comment: Thanks for posting more details. I see that when i populate the fields with javascript the response comes in blank. I'll look into this more. I believe this is something related to the built in spam prevention office.forms has, but i see nothing about spam prevention. I'd recommend you also post your question on the office.forms forum: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms/bd-p/MicrosoftForms

Comment: if you populate the fields manually typing. then change them via javascript. then when the submit is pressed you can see for a second, the values change back to the original values. this is differently some front side javascript spam prevention. They also do not use a <form> element so we can't manually trigger the form submission with javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it @NickTimmer. Is there another way by which I can set the values of the field?

Comment: I don't think so with those office.forms, its really hard for me to follow what exactly the minified javascript is doing.. I see it hit the react code, but I get lost after that. Again I would ask on the Forms I linked above.

Comment: Hey @Nick I just got an idea. Is there any way we can simulate a key stroke? like after our scanned barcode is typed. we use these commands:- `abc.focus; abc.select(); *then we simulate a keypress like any char 'x' and the simulate a backspace? * ` I am weak at javascript so if you can help me with the command for simulating a stroke, that would be great.

Comment: @Shezratnani i just noticed you accepted my answer, but I don't think it really helped. I got busy on a project so havent been on here. But Um I tried simulating keypresses and couldn't get it to work that way either. If you haven't already I'd post question on : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms/bd-p/MicrosoftForms on how to populate fields with javascript as you explained in this question.